# How can I display a CSS linear gradient in Netscape?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, netscape

How do I use a CSS linear gradient with Netscape?

I am trying this code:

```
#gr {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#000));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff,  #000);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000');
    -ms-filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000'); 
}
```

It works with IE, Firefox, and Chrome but it does not work with Netscape.

Comment: `AOL formally stopped development of Netscape Navigator on December 28, 2007, but continued supporting the web browser with security updates until March 1, 2008, when AOL canceled technical support.` 
Why would you want to support netscape, chances of a user using your site from netscape is slim to none?

Comment: AS @JohnRiselvato said, I am pretty sure nobody still use Netscape..

Comment: Wow, Netscape? What are the requirements for this project? That's like supporting Windows 3.1

Comment: It's probably a control freak client!

Comment: While we're at it, how about support in Mosaic too?

Comment: i am netscape user ...

Comment: he would use netscape. @Alaa, have you ever seen any gradient while using netscape on daily browsing? Might be a good idea to look at that sites css source.

Comment: @John you're right, and you've experience in persuasion, even google is not working fine with netscape!! Thank you all, and i am sorry for my ambigus question

Comment: Quite difficult for a browser to support a feature added AFTER its development stopped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Netscape Navigator 9, last updated between 2006 and 2008 as a Firefox derivative, does not offer any real support for CSS beyond a large subset of the CSS2.1 spec. It does not support CSS3 gradients, or most any other CSS3 feature.

Netscape Navigator/Communicator 4.x and older don't have a lot of CSS support at all.

If you really need a gradient, you're better off using a background image. That's the traditional, tried and tested method designers have been using for the past 10 years, with great cross-browser compatibility yet very little friction.

If you're trying to support Netscape only because you are a Netscape user, stop wasting your time. Switch to Firefox. No serious web designer uses Netscape anymore in this day and age.

Comment: and @sohaan gets down votes for the same idea and basic answer.

Comment: @John Riselvato: It was very poorly-written at the time it collected downvotes, especially having a typo in the CSS property and not being formatted properly. See the original revision. The downvoters have been given an opportunity to take away their votes since it has been edited, but they quite simply haven't done so (and they still can!). I posted mainly to offer a bit of historical insight beyond the basic answer.

Answer (score 2):

Netscape is no longer supported and is very rarely used by anyone.

But if you still want to use a linear gradient on your site, you can create an image using Photoshop or any other graphic editor, and then use it as:

```
background-image: url('url-of-img.jpg');
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If alaa really wants gradient with netscape, this might be the best way.

Comment: Thank you john, and i did't make downvote, and i appreciate your response, but i am building big website that support all languages&browsers, i am not photoshop designer, I hope to find another solution

Comment: hey @AlaaGamal as i can see in you question you are going from  #ffffff to  #000 i.e from extreme white to extreme black to create a gradient image for this combination you dont need to be photoshop designer if you have photoshop installed then you have what you want as template in photoshop you just need to go select that template and create image within few clicks good luck

Comment: Someone probably downvoted because you stubbornly refused to type `y` and `o` before your `u`. Rather than adding a downvote of my own, I just fixed the problem so I wouldn't have to look at it anymore.

Comment: I downvoted you because background-img isn't a CSS property, it's background-image